# What does the .git folder not contain?

Tags: git

From the [git site](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain) (emphasis mine):

> When you run git init in a new or existing directory, Git creates the
>   .git directory, which is where **almost** everything that Git stores and
>   manipulates is located. If you want to back up or clone your
>   repository, copying this single directory elsewhere gives you **nearly**
>   everything you need.

They sneak "almost" and "nearly" in there without elaborating. What *isn't* located in the .git directory? If I want to back up or clone my repository, what does copying that single directory elsewhere *not* give me?

Comment: The global configs are not contained within the `.git` directory

Comment: @Maze But they are not repository specific.

Comment: @TimWolla: True, but they're things that "Git stores and manipulates".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Git does not record:

- file groups
- file owners
- file permissions (other than "is this executable")
- extended attributes
- empty folders
- (anything in `.gitignore`, but that's probably desired)
- gitmodules

Probably [this post](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) can provide you more insights

Comment: The things that Git doesn't record is different than the things that you don't get when copy a `.git` directory

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple other `.git` files that make up your repository outside of the `.git` folder itself, in particular, you have:

```
.gitignore # contains the files that you do not want in the repository
.gitmodules # contains the information on submodules
```

As well if you have a submodule, you will have a plain text file `.git` that points back to the "real repository directory" - see [git Repository Layout Docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout)

Comment: Do you not check those in?  If not, why not?

Comment: I don't think that you check in the `.git` plain text file, but I could be wrong. I have seen people both check in and not check in the `.gitignore` file

Answer (score 1):

Your user/global configuration file is typically in `~/.gitconfig`

The system configuration file is typically in `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`

Submodule information would be stored in the top level of your working directory in a  `.gitmodules` file

Information about ignoring files could come from any number of `.gitignore` files in your working directory.  But it could also come from a excludes file via `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global` or similar.

If you have an alternate object store or a reference repository configured in `.git/objects/info/alternates`, then you will have external object dependencies.