# How does GitHub know what commits I've made in my local repository?

Tags: git, github

I've read the documentation and searched Google but I just don't understand this.

I made a local repository on my machine, made commits to it and then 3 days later I made a GitHub repository and pushed the local repository to it.

The GitHub repository says there have been 2 commits. How does GitHub know of my local repository's history?

Comment: Github knows because you pushed it?

Comment: Pushing means sending commits to a remote repo.

Comment: Github doesn't know anything about your local repo. It has its own copy of the repo.

Comment: Yes but, that’s a very basic level of understanding and i need to understand how it actually works.
I mean, what exactly is being git pushed that has history of my commits? I know that git push “Updates remote refs using local refs, while sending objects necessary to complete the given refs.” but this does not actually say how it does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sent your commits to GitHub when you pushed.

---

The `git` documentation is very abstract, so I'm not sure how much use it is for a beginner, but for what it's worth, here's the description about [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> Updates remote refs using local refs, while sending objects necessary to complete the given refs.

In this case, "refs" means the commit history, and "objects" means the data contained in the commits.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have read that description but i wanted to understand deeper, how does "git push" give that information?  i know theres a hidden .git folder that contains all of that information, is that folder also pushed(uploaded) to github but not shown?

Comment: @jjkin It's not something I know too much about myself, but based on the above description, no, only the refs and objects are pushed, not the whole .git folder.

Comment: I think refs might actually be pointers like beaches and tags which point to objects. Objects are the commits (and trees, files, etc)

Comment: @evolution Maybe, but I don't want to overcomplicate it for OP. I don't know it too well myself anyway.

Comment: Beaches... I meant branches 

Comment: so if refs and objects are pushed to github, why don't they appear with the project on github? i un-hid the .git folder on windows and pushed again but theres no sign of it on github. i know theres no actual need to see it, but it would help my understanding of how everything actually works.

Comment: @jkin Like you said, there's no actual need to see it, so GitHub doesn't show it. In fact there's not really any need to see it on your computer for that matter since it's not supposed to be modified directly. It's a bit of a black box.

Comment: @jjkin You'll probably be interested in this btw: [What does the .git folder not contain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30005991/4518341)